# maven: using self written plugin: not downloaded

Tags: maven, plugins

I wrote a maven plugin myself

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>eu.simuline.m2latex</groupId>
    <artifactId>latex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
</plugin>
```

and it works just fine if I have it locally stored at `~/.m2/repository`,
but if I clean up then it tries to download
but fetches something totally different:

```
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/latex-maven-plugin/1.1/latex-maven-plugin-1.1.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/latex-maven-plugin/1.1/latex-maven-plugin-1.1.jar (11 kB at 48 kB/s)
```

It then uses this plugin and it fails of course because it has not the same targets.
What happens here?????

I am quite sure that I declared the source repository correctly:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>publicRepoAtSimuline</id>
      <name>repo at simuline</name>
      <url>https://www.simuline.eu/RepositoryMaven</url>
    </repository>
    ...

  </repositories>
```

because at the given location I can see the correct artifacts.

Comment: Please show full pom file...and the reason why you are writing plugins... ?

Comment: I write a plugin for documentation in latex. But since i have special needs, i ventured to write my own plugin.

Comment: The problem with the full pom is, that the project is not open source.. hm.. Never had this problem... Maybe... Maybe i can create a smaller pom with the same defect.. Wait..

Comment: Intresting because the repository which is defined can be accessed without credentials. https://www.simuline.eu/RepositoryMaven/eu/simuline/m2latex/latex-maven-plugin/ ???? My question keeps. Why are you writing a plugin and why kind of problem are you trying to solve... Furthermore if this is non public repository you should use a repository manager inside your organisation (for example Nexus)... and also never define a repository in your pom file ...only in your `settings.xml` file...

Comment: https://www.simuline.eu/RepositoryMaven/eu/simuline/m2latex/latex-maven-plugin/1.6-SNAPSHOT/latex-maven-plugin-1.6-20220618.125049-26.pom (From what I can see here: There are so many things wrong in that pom file .. I can't even count..

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/reallyinsane/mathan-latex-maven-plugin